# PHPMailer não envia hospedado

Tags: php

Olá pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site, e ele terá uma pagina de contato então estou usando o plugin phpmailer, quando ele está localmente ele envia o e-mail corretamente, porém quando hospedo o e-mail não envia e da a seguinte mensagem

**/home/u692630104/public_html/app/PHPMailer.class.php**

Código:

```
<?php

/**
 * descricao EmailEnviar
 *
  * @author adrianosites.com.br
    */
  class EmailEnviar extends PHPMailer {


/**
 * inicia os dados de conexao com o host
 * 
 */
function __construct() {

    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->isHTML(true);
    $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $this->Port = 587;
    $this->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";  
    $this->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
    $this->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $this->Username   = "rogeriobarro500@hotmail.com"; 
    $this->Password   = "xxxxxxxxx";        // SMTP account password
    //$this->SetFrom('rogeriobarro500@hotmail.com', 'Acordo Imovel');
    $this->From  = 'rogeriobarro500@hotmail.com';
    $this->FromName = 'Acordo Imóvel';


}

/**
 * 
 * @param type $destinatario
 * @param type $assunto
 * @param type $msg
 * 
 *  envia o email
 */
public function Enviar($destinatario,$assunto,$msg) {



    $this->Subject = $assunto;
    $this->addAddress($destinatario);
    $this->Body = $msg;


    if(parent::send()):

        parent::clearAllRecipients();
        else:

        echo 'erro no envio' . $this->ErrorInfo ;
    endif;


}


 }
```

Comment: Conferiu com sua hospedagem se eles não tem nenhuma restrição a envio de emails com php? Tive um problema recente e tive que mudar de hospedagem por que eles não tinham suporte a smtp.

Comment: Poxa eu não sei, é que eu estou hospedando gratuitamente no hostinger só para ver se não tem nenhum erro, depois eu irei hospedar na locaweb

Comment: Imagino que esteja ok a parte da programação por que funcionou localmente.

Answer (score 0):

A hospedagem (hostinger) que você está usando bloqueia o acesso a porta 587 para usuarios do plano free. Em qualquer um dos planos premios seu codigo deve funcionar.

Comment: Então se será que na locaweb funciona direitinho?

Comment: Funciona. Já enviei emails com smtp usando o plano mais basico deles.